# Applescript or Terminal : Add a event on calendar

Tags: macos, terminal, calendar, applescript

I try to make a calendar event from terminal,

here is my code

```
tell application "Calendar"
    activate
    tell calendar "Calendar"
        set theCurrentDate to current date
        make new event at end with properties {description:"Event Decription", summary:"Event Name", location:"Event Location", start date:theCurrentDate, end date:theCurrentDate + 510 * minutes}
    end tell
    reload calendars
end tell
```

It's doing the job but it's really slow, and need to open calendar,
any faster way to do it, if possible without opening calendar ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the "activate" and the "reload calendar, it is faster. 
It just opens the application Calendar, but does not display any window of it !